# String / template literals extension not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, syntax

So my backtick isnt converting to string literals / isnt being picked up. I have this react component section:

```
export default function ValidatorForm(props) {
  return (
    <section className=``>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </section>
  );
}
```

And im getting an red errors as if they werent recognised. On my windows pc it works fine and even in stack overflow now the 3 backticks to show code is working. VSCode isnt picking it up though. I could use "" and + "" to inject stuff but template literals are my go to thing and look much cleaner. I cant see why it wouldnt work

Comment: why is the use triple backticks at SO important in writing React code, so in VSC. If you would use Notepad you get the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As its React, I completely forgot i should havve used `{}` and then the backticks inside.

Comment: mistakes like these happen every once in a while...

Comment: You may want to amend this with the actual code that fixes it. This description is a bit hazy.